# Does moments minimization implies CDF maximization?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, moments

I have a non-negative random variable $X$ with a continuously differentiable PDF $f(x|\theta)$, where $x\geq0$ and $\theta$ is the distribution parameter. The corresponding CDF is $F(x|\theta)$. I don't know the exact form of PDF and CDF but I can find a parameter value $\theta_0$ that minimizes all the moments $\mu_k(\theta) = \mathbb{E}_\theta[X^k]$:
$$
\mu_k(\theta_0) \leq \mu_k(\theta), \quad \forall k>0.
$$
Intuitively, this means that the value $\theta_0$ squeezes the distribution towards $x=0$ as mush as possible and, as a result, maximizes CDF at any point:
$$
F(x|\theta_0) \geq F(x|\theta), \quad \forall x\geq0.
$$
Is this proposition true? If so, how can it be proved?

### Update

I would like to also mention that in my case $\theta_0$ is the local extremum of $\mu_k(\theta)$ for every $k$:
$$
\frac{\partial \mu_k(\theta)}{\partial \theta}\bigg|_{\theta=\theta_0}=0, \quad \forall k>0.
$$
According to [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281479001_Some_properties_of_moment-empirical_CDF%27s_with_application_to_some_inverse_estimation_problems), CDF could be expressed via moments as
$$
F(x|\theta) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{ \sum_{k=0}^{[nx]}{ \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}{\frac{(-n)^{j-k}n^k}{(j-k)!k!}\mu_k(\theta)} } }, \quad x\geq0.
$$
Hence $\theta_0$ is also an extremum of $F(x|\theta)$ for every value of $x$. However, it does not tell me whether $\theta_0$ is the global (or even local) maximum.

Comment: This is not true in general, so don't attempt a proof: construct a counterexample. Consider, for instance, the family of uniform distributions on the intervals $(\theta,2-\theta)$ for $0\le\theta\le 1.$